# Custom scrollbar in web browser - drag and move vs infinite scroll - jumping content

Tags: linux, firefox, scrolling, extension

I've got a mouse wheel broken (spinning with resistance) and that's why I use drag and move on the scrollbar slider.

And today's Internet is not adapted to it - By infinite scroll.

While holding, additional content loads into the page and the slider is shortened, its position changes and the page jumps and you can get lost where you were last.

Is there an extension or other solution so that this does not happen?
Any custom scrollbar that you can use by dragging with infinite scroll?

Comment: You could just tap the spacebar, that's pretty universal for 'scroll a page', or you could get a working mouse.

Comment: I know but I don't want to. It's about situations where I can use only one hand held on the mouse.

Comment: Then buy a new mouse.

Comment: This is another mouse that breaks down soon after buying. I am discouraged from buying another.

Comment: Then buy a **decent** mouse.

Comment: I currently have Logitech G102.

Comment: Jej, you could try to find an app that allows so called "drag scroll" (just move the mouse up or down to scroll). For Windows there are some, and I've written one in Autohotkey, but I don't know any for Linux. Though try searching "drag scroll" or something for Linux.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/8000/mouseimp-alternative-on-linux-drag-and-scroll